# Scala Spark Streaming Via Apache Toree

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am using the all-spark notebook docker image on my mac to use apache toree and scala (https://github.com/jupyter/docker-stacks/tree/master/all-spark-notebook ).

I am trying to test the basic streaming example of spark's documentation, wich involve to :
1) start a sparkstreaming object, listening on port 9999
2) start the netcast program : `nc -lk 9999`

So I launch the container binding the 9999 port :

```
$ sudo docker run -it --rm -p 9999:9999 -p 8888:8888 -e GRANT_SUDO=yes --user root --pid=host -e TINI_SUBREAPER=true  -v $HOME/Informatique/notebooks:/home/jovyan/work:rw jupyter/all-spark-notebook
```

But then, trying to connect to it I got a "port already used" error :

```
$ nc -lk 9999
nc: Address already in use
```

I also tried to put myself in the container :

```
romain@MacBook-Pro-de-oursin:~$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                        COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                            NAMES
0bd6b70bacfa        jupyter/all-spark-notebook   "tini -- start-not..."   23 seconds ago      Up 22 seconds       0.0.0.0:8888->8888/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9999->9999/tcp   wonderful_brattain
romain@MacBook-Pro-de-oursin:~$ docker exec -ti wonderful_brattain  /bin/bash
root@0bd6b70bacfa:~/work# nc -lk 9999
bash: nc: command not found
root@0bd6b70bacfa:~/work# sudo apt-get update
root@0bd6b70bacfa:~/work# sudo apt-get install netcat-traditional
root@0bd6b70bacfa:~/work# nc -lk 9999
aaaa aaa aaa
bb bbb bbb
cc cc cc
```

But there is nothing displayed on the scala notebook :

```
import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark.streaming._
import org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext._ 
val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[2]").setAppName("NetworkWordCount")
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(1))
val lines = ssc.socketTextStream("localhost", 9999)
val words = lines.flatMap(_.split(" "))
import org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext._ // not necessary since Spark 1.3
// Count each word in each batch
val pairs = words.map(word => (word, 1))
val wordCounts = pairs.reduceByKey(_ + _)
// Print the first ten elements of each RDD generated in this DStream to the console
wordCounts.print()
```

with :

```
ssc.start()             // Start the computation
ssc.awaitTermination()  // Wait for the computation to terminate
```

gives :

```
-------------------------------------------
Time: 1485880101000 ms
-------------------------------------------

-------------------------------------------
Time: 1485880102000 ms
-------------------------------------------

-------------------------------------------
Time: 1485880103000 ms
-------------------------------------------

-------------------------------------------
Time: 1485880104000 ms
-------------------------------------------
```

How to deal with these network issues ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Spark streaming context tries to connect to the `nc` server to stream data from it.  It's the `nc` server that is listening on port 9999, **not** the Spark context.

You're getting the port already in use error because you first start your notebook container with `-p 9999:9999`, so Docker reserves port 9999 on your host.  When you then try to run `nc -lk 9999` on your host, you get the conflict.

You need to setup the `nc` server so that the kernel running within your notebook container can access it.  One way to do this is to run the `nc` server in a separate Docker container, and have both containers connect to the same Docker network.

First, create a Docker network on your host to allow the two containers to communicate:

```
docker network create testnet
```

Now run `nc` in its own container.

```
docker run -it --rm --name nc --network testnet appropriate/nc -lk 9999
```

The `--network testnet` option attaches the container to the `testnet` network.  The `--name nc` option makes the container accessible to other containers on the same network using the hostname `nc`.

Now run the notebook container separately.  It should also use `--network testnet`.

```
docker run -it --rm --network testnet -p 8888:8888 \
-v $HOME/Informatique/notebooks:/home/jovyan/work:rw \
jupyter/all-spark-notebook
```

Finally, in your notebook code, make sure the Spark context connects to hostname `nc`.

```
import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark.streaming._
import org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext._ 
val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[2]").setAppName("NetworkWordCount")
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(5))
val lines = ssc.socketTextStream("nc", 9999)
val words = lines.flatMap(_.split(" "))
import org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext._ 
// Count each word in each batch
val pairs = words.map(word => (word, 1))
val wordCounts = pairs.reduceByKey(_ + _)
// Print the first ten elements of each RDD generated in this DStream to the console
wordCounts.print()

ssc.start()             // Start the computation
ssc.awaitTermination()  // Wait for the computation to terminate
```

If you type in the terminal for the `nc` container:

```
hello, world
```

You should see this in your notebook:

```
-------------------------------------------
Time: 1485987495000 ms
-------------------------------------------
(hello,,1)
(world,1)
```